# React-Redux how to dispatch an action

Tags: redux, react-redux, action

I'm currently learning redux, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to dispatch an action. I have a component with an input field, and what I would like to happen is for the text that the user types in to be saved so that I can show it on another page.

Here is my action:

```
export const addMovement = () => {
    const response = {
        movement: {
            name: '',
            weight: '',
        } 
    }

    return {
        type: constants.ADD_MOVEMENT,
        payload: response
    }
   
};
```

Here is my reducer:

```
const intialState = {
    movement: {
        name: '',
        weight: '',
    } 
};

const movementReducer = (state = intialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_MOVEMENT:
            return [ ...state, action.payload ]
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default movementReducer;
```

Here is my component:

```
const AddPage = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [weight, setWeight] = useState(0);
    const onSubmit = () => {
        addMovement();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Header title="Add Page" />
            <div>
                <div>
                    <TextField  
                        key="name" 
                        label="Enter Movement Name" 
                        InputProps= {{className: "textBoxColor"}}
                        variant="outlined"
                        onChange={event => {
                            const { value } = event.target;
                            setName(value);
                        }} 
                         />    
                    <TextField 
                        key="weight" 
                        label="Enter Movement Weight" 
                        type="number" 
                        variant="outlined"
                        onChange={event => {
                            const { value } = event.target;
                            setWeight(value);
                        }}
                        InputProps= {{endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">lb</InputAdornment> }} />
                    <Button 
                        variant="outlined"
                        onClick={ onSubmit }
                        >
                        <AddCircleIcon />
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        newName: state.name,
        newWeight: state.weight,
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return (
        dispatch(addMovement)
    )
};

const withConnect = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
);

export default compose(withConnect)(AddPage)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can be best explained with an example

If you want to set current user object in redux state

```js
export const SetcurrentUser = user => ({
    type: 'SET_CURRENT_USER',
    payload: user
});
```

In order to call SetcurretnUser action with a user parameter.

```js
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return({
        SetcurrentUser: (user) => dispatch(SetcurrentUser(user))
    })
}
```

**Now in your case:**

#### Case:1 If your Redux state needs a payload

```js
//take response as parameter in your action you may destructure it if necessary

export const addMovement = (response) => {
    return {
        type: constants.ADD_MOVEMENT,
        payload: response
    }
   
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return({
        addMovement: (response) => dispatch(addMovement(response))
    })
}
```

#### Case:2 If only action is needed no payload

```js
export const addMovement = () => {
    return {
        type: constants.ADD_MOVEMENT,
    }
   
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return({
        addMovement: () => dispatch(addMovement())
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! The example with payload is what worked for me. I finally have the action doing what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

As you are learning, you can use functional components with hooks. In redux hooks, it is easy to read from the store as well as to dispatch actions using `useSelector()` and `useDispatch()` hooks.

```
const items = useSelector(state => state.reducerName.itemName)
```

You can try to write you code using functional components as it is recommended from React community